# Datastructures problem in asp.net/c#

Tags: asp.net, arraylist

I have a e-commerce web application which allows users to buy software components in my website. I'm retrieving the invoice number and the software component title that was bought by the user from UserTransactionHistory table in sql server. I'm storing them in arraylist with the help of a SoftwareTitles Class

```
 public class SoftwareTitles
{
    string softwareTitle;
    string invoiceNumber;

    public SoftwareTitles(string softwareTitle, string invoiceNumber)
    {
        this.softwareTitle = softwareTitle;
        this.invoiceNumber = invoiceNumber;
    }

    string InvoiceNumber
    {           
        get
        {
            return this.invoiceNumber;
        }
    }

    string SoftwareTitle
    {
        get
        {
            return this.softwareTitle;
        }
    }
}
```

}

And I'm adding this class to arraylist in this manner.

```
ConnectionToSql con1 = new ConnectionToSql();
        string connectionString = con1.ConnectionStringMethod();
        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SelectionOfSoftwareTitles", sqlConnection);
        cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlConnection.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr2.HasRows)
        {
            while (dr2.Read())
            {
                String softwareTitle = (String)dr2[0];
                String invoiceNumber = (String)dr2[1];
                softwareTitlesArray.Add(new SoftwareTitles(softwareTitle, invoiceNumber));
                int i = 0;

            }

        }

        sqlConnection.Close();
        dr2.Close();
```

But when I want to retrieve all the software titles that are associated with a certain Invoice number. I'm not able to do it.

Am i doing it properly ?? Is arraylist appropriate data structure for such operation ?? How should I do it ?

Comment: @klabranche As you can see it is a multidimensional arraylist. I want to retrieve values from this arraylist depending upon the invoicenumber. Something along these lines: for(int j=0; j<softwareTitlesArrayList.count; j++){softwareTitlesArrayList[j,0].contains("InvoiceNumber"){dosomething...}} I'm not even able to refer the items in this multi-dimensional arraylist. I don't know how to do that. Can u help me. How to search for contents in the multi-dimensional array?? and how to traverse the multi-dimensional arraylist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would personally use a non-generic list object.

To declare:

```
List<Software> softwareTitles= New List<Software>();
```

And the object software:

```
if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                string title = dr["TITLE_COLUMN"];
                int invoice = dr["INVOICE_COLUMN"];
                Software s = new Software();
                s.Title = title;
                s.Invoice = invoice;
                softwareTitles.add(s);

            }

        }
```

and then you can traverse through the list using a simple loop and counter like,  softwareTitles(i) or you can even use LINQ to accomplish whatever you want to do.
e.g.

```
for (i=0; i<softwareTitles.Count;i++)
{
  if (softwareTitles[i].Invoice==213)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(softwareTitles[i].Title);
  }
}
```

Somthing like that. Sorry I am using VB.NET lately, so my C# has become rusty. But it seems correct

Comment: but how do i retrieve the value from this list depending upon invoicenumber.

Comment: i cannot reference the list items like what you have mentioned. I meant softwareTitles(i).Invoice=213   It is just freaking out !!

Comment: oops.. and square brackets also :)

Comment: Software software213 = softwareTitles.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Invoice == 213);

Answer (score 1):

Use Generic List Collection  to add the Objects and Linq to Query the Records.

Comment: i'm not using linq in my project

Comment: Then use stored procedures to filter the records while retrieving it self.